# How to write a complex no linear term in loop of a differential equation system?

Tags: differential-equations, complex, infinite-loop

I have this system of equations

$$
i \frac{d \psi_{m}}{dt} = k \psi_{m-1} + k \psi_{m+1} + \gamma \vert \psi_{m} \vert^{2} \psi_{m}
$$

and this is my code

```
In[1]:= Clear["Global`*"]

In[2]:= SeedRandom[1234]

In[3]:= tini = 0;

In[4]:= tmax = 200

Out[4]= 200

In[5]:= Nmax = 5;

In[6]:= n0 = 5;

In[7]:= \[Gamma] = 1;

In[27]:= k = 1;

In[9]:= m = Nmax - 1;

In[10]:= \[Psi][0][t] = 0;

In[11]:= \[Psi][Nmax + 1][t] = 0;

In[15]:= \[Psi]ini = Table[KroneckerDelta[n0 - i], {i, 1, Nmax}];

In[16]:= S1 = Table[I Derivative[1][\[Psi][i]][t], {i, 1, Nmax}];

In[17]:= S2 = 
  Table[k \[Psi][i - 1][t] + k \[Psi][i + 1][t], {i, 1, Nmax}];

In[18]:= S3 = \[Gamma] Table[\[Psi][i][t], {i, 1, Nmax}];

In[19]:= S4 = Table[Abs[\[Psi][i]]^2, {i, 1, Nmax}];

In[20]:= S3S4 = Thread[S3*S4];

In[21]:= S22 = Thread[S2 + S3S4];

In[22]:= S1S22 = Thread[S1 == S22];

In[23]:= S000 = Thread[Table[\[Psi][i][0], {i, 1, Nmax}] == \[Psi]ini];

In[24]:= TTotal = Join[S1S22, S000]

Out[24]= {I Derivative[1][\[Psi][1]][t] == 
  Abs[\[Psi][1]]^2 \[Psi][1][t] + \[Psi][2][t], 
 I Derivative[1][\[Psi][2]][t] == \[Psi][1][t] + 
   Abs[\[Psi][2]]^2 \[Psi][2][t] + \[Psi][3][t], 
 I Derivative[1][\[Psi][3]][t] == \[Psi][2][t] + 
   Abs[\[Psi][3]]^2 \[Psi][3][t] + \[Psi][4][t], 
 I Derivative[1][\[Psi][4]][t] == \[Psi][3][t] + 
   Abs[\[Psi][4]]^2 \[Psi][4][t] + \[Psi][5][t], 
 I Derivative[1][\[Psi][5]][t] == \[Psi][4][t] + 
   Abs[\[Psi][5]]^2 \[Psi][5][t], \[Psi][1][0] == 0, \[Psi][2][0] == 
  0, \[Psi][3][0] == 0, \[Psi][4][0] == 0, \[Psi][5][0] == 1}

In[25]:= SS0 = Table[\[Psi][i], {i, 1, Nmax}]

Out[25]= {\[Psi][1], \[Psi][2], \[Psi][3], \[Psi][4], \[Psi][5]}

In[26]:= usol = NDSolveValue[TTotal, SS0, {t, tini, tmax}];
```

My question is, am I writing the no linear term in my equation? That´s the reason for which my program doesn´t work?

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is it that doesn’t work with this, exactly?

Comment: The error is this: NDSolveValue::dvnoarg: The function \[Psi][1] appears with no arguments.

Comment: Miguel, it is better to update your question with such information, as it is not as easily seen nor as beneficial being in the comments, as it would be being an update to your question.

Comment: To directly address the error you posted, look at your `S4`, there is no argument in such definition. I have not seen anything else, but it will benefit you to investigate sources of the error such as that which I mentioned.